# ¿Border-image es compartible con todos los dispositivos y navegadores?

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Buen día comunidad!
Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con HTML, CSS y Bootstrap (responsive y con @mediaqueries) para algunos bordes estoy utilizando degradado linear. Lo que sucede es que en desktop con diferentes navegadores es exactamente el diseño que pensamos, ya en mobile su comportamiento cambia según el navegador y dispositivo. Buscando diferentes soluciones antes de realizar la pregunta instale prefix-free (http://projects.verou.me/prefixfree/) y también utilice el debug prefix de VS Code. Nada de esto dio resultado dado que el comportamiento continua cambiando.
Les envío el código para su revisión y en caso de que puedan ayudarme estaría muy agradecido.

```
 #mensaje {
 border: 1.5px solid transparent;
-moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,#a0dc56 0%, #0b9484 100%);
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#a0dc56 0%, #0b9484 100%);
 border-image: linear-gradient(to right,#a0dc56 0%, #0b9484 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 }
```

Acompaño los errores con imágenes para facilitar su comprensión:

[image: Borde derecho únicamente - Desktop]
[image: Borde derecho únicamente - Mobile error]

[image: Borde superior únicamente - Desktop]
[image: Borde superior únicamente - Mobile error]

[image: Borde integral - Desktop]
[image: Borde integral - Mobile error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para todos aquellos que tengan la misma dificultad en sus sitios, principalmente en mobile, les comento que continué mi investigación, mi error radicaba en no utilizar correctamente la propiedad **border-image-slice** que asigna valores a los lados (top, right, bottom, and left). Siendo que el valor 1 es el total integral de los bordes.
A continuación facilito un fragmento del código correcto para su posible utilización:

```
    -moz-border: 1.5px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border: 1.5px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffaa2d 0%, #eb4375 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffaa2d 0%, #eb4375 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right,#ffaa2d 0%, #eb4375 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1 0;
```

Muchas gracias a la comunidad

Answer (score 1):

De lo que pude observar no en todos está soportado completamente existen algunos bugs. Esta herramienta te puede ayudar a revisar la compatibilidad con los navegadores. Te sirve para html, css y js(este no estoy muy seguro pues depende mas del motor del navegador).

[Can I use](https://caniuse.com)

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, es una excelente herramienta.Slds